# Dell XPS 9570 BIOS downgrade issue (i7-8750H)

Tags: windows, bios, firmware, intel-core-i7, dell-xps

I'm trying to perform a BIOS downgrade from 1.16.2 back to 1.15.0, but keep getting the error:

> ME Firmware EndUpdate Failed Error 0x000001F3

The downgrade is initiated from Windows without error or warning. It is during the actual firmware update at boot time when the error occurs, during the Intel Management Engine update. That is the only component that fails, and even though the final status message reports a failure, all other components' version numbers reflect a successful update (including the BIOS version).

However, my problem is that I still can no longer modify the processor core voltage offset from Intel XTU, and so my laptop runs around 90-99 degrees under most workloads, sustained. I'm therefore assuming that this lock-out is related to the Management Engine "security" update in 1.16.2.

**Is there any other way to downgrade the Intel Management Engine?** I've tried installing 1.15 twice, 1.14 once, and also did a rollback operation from BIOS Recovery. However, all attempts result in the same error.

**Disk Work**

[image: disk work - task]

[image: disk work - xtu]

**CPU Work**

[image: cpu work - task]

[image: cpu work - xtu]